# Getting cookies causing error 500

Tags: php, google-chrome, cookies

I am getting seriously frustrated that I can't get this to work. I've tried a few different approaches to this, and from all the examples and code I've read this SHOULD be working, but it isn't.

```
2012-10-19 19:24:04.533 192.168.1.62 "-" "WEBMATRIX" "-" 192.168.1.62 POST /Actions/NewTicket.php - 500 0 6149 688 45 -11640 "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1229.94 Safari/537.4" "QCUserID=1" "http://192.168.1.62:53896/NewTicketPage.html" "-" "192.168.1.62:53896" 0
```

WebMatrix/Actions/login.php <- This works. I can see it in my cookies in Chrome. and it looks like it is in the log error.

```
<?php 
//set vars
require_once(__DIR__ . "/GlobalCookies.php");

GC_ClearCookie("QCUserID");
$user = $_POST['username'];
$pass = $_POST['password'];

require_once(__DIR__ . "/db.php");

$query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM users WHERE UserInitials='%s' AND UserPassword='%s'", mysql_real_escape_string($user),mysql_real_escape_string($pass));
$result = mysql_query($query);
$rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

if($rows!=0)
{
    $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
    GC_SetCookie("QCUserID", $row[0]);
    header("refresh:0;url=../DashboardPage.php");
}
else
{
    echo("User Not Found, redirecting to login page in 3 seconds");
    header("refresh:3;url=../index.php");
}

?>
```

WebMatrix/Actions/GlobalCookies.php <- strange that it doesn't get the ?> at the end of the file.. I didn't look up how to do a functions file, I just copied some of it from Mantisbt. but it throws a error 500 if i have it and try to use it in login.php

```
<?php
function GC_GetCookie( $p_var_name, $p_default = null )
{
    if( isset( $_COOKIE[$p_var_name] ) )
    {
        $t_result = gpc_strip_slashes( $_COOKIE[$p_var_name] );
    }
    else if( func_num_args() > 1 )
    {
        //check for a default passed in (allowing null)
        $t_result = $p_default;
    }
    else
    {
        error_parameters( $p_var_name );
        trigger_error( ERROR_GPC_VAR_NOT_FOUND, ERROR );
    }

    return $t_result;
}
function GC_SetCookie($p_name, $p_value, $p_httponly = true)
{
    return setcookie( $p_name, $p_value, 36000, "/");
}
function GC_ClearCookie($p_name)
{
    return setcookie( $p_name, '', -1, "/" );
}
```

WebMatrix/Actions/NewTicket.php <- this fails

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1);

require_once(__DIR__ . "/db.php");
require_once(__DIR__ . "/GlobalCookies.php");

$serial = $_POST['serialNumber'];
$model = $_POST['modelNumber'];
$company = $_POST['companyName'];
$special = $_POST['specialNote'];
$userID = GC_GetCookie("QCUserID",1); //Error 500 here
echo($userID."<br>");
?>
```

This seems like such a simple thing, but I've been trying for a few days.. and my searches on Google is turning up nothing. Thank you for your time.... For giggles i tried it in IE on a different computer, and it works.... strange.

Comment: Can you post the entry from the error log that corresponds with the 50?

Comment: `gpc_strip_slashes()` is not a native PHP function, it's from Mantis and you're not defining it. That is likely the cause of the error.

Comment: Do you have the function `gpc_strip_slashes` defined anywhere?  Add `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` at the beginning of your PHP file during testing, it will tell you the error message instead of a generic 500 page.  Also you can check the server error_log file for the cause of the PHP error.

Comment: @Pekka I feel so silly, i can't believe I missed that. Interesting that IE didn't seem to care, and went ahead and processed it anyway. I got rid of the strip slashes and now it is working in chrome. Thank you everyone. Now to find out why it's not pulling correct result from  db.

Comment: @RobertSnyder :) thanks for posting a detailed question though, +1 for being thorough so we could identify the issue quickly.  As for IE, it may have been using a cached copy, its pretty terrible about that with the default settings.

Comment: @drew010 thank you for that. Strange my GC_SetCookie isn't working now. I noticed in my DB that my user ID was 1, when it should be 3. Out of curiosity I deleted the cookie from Chrome, and it has yet to be put back in. I've checked my log and it doesn't show anythign about it... Guess i'll keep looking

Comment: @Pekka I'm affraid I don't know what you are asking me to post. What specifically should I be looking for that tells me that it corresponds to 50?

Comment: @Robert I meant the 500. That part is solved I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For setting your cookie, try changing:

```
setcookie( $p_name, $p_value, 36000, "/");
```

to:

```
setcookie( $p_name, $p_value, time() + 36000, "/");
```

The reason is because the expiration parameter is a Unix timestamp so you have to add the current time to however many seconds you want it to expire in.

Are you using this cookie solely for the purpose of identifying if a user is logged in?  If so, all I would need to do to log in as a different user would be to create a cookie with the appropriate name and pick a random user id if that were the case.

Comment: I guess i need a break from this, because at one time my setcookie command had that in their. Thank you for catching that... ugh... Good thing i'm not a HUGE newb :/ oh wait, I am.

Comment: I just saw what you said about the user id... this is very true you could, if you could access my intranet. :) I do need to find a better way of doing this. One thing I found was $_SESSION[]. I started using it a little bit, but sometimes it confuses me a little bit. But that is what learning is all about, trying something..then trying something else. Thank you for your answer

Comment: Yeah sessions are what you want in this case.  Put simply, as long as you have `session_start();` called at the beginning of your requests, you can read and store values in the `$_SESSION` array.  As long as the cookie sent by the browser matches an existing session, the right data will be available for that request.  You can then store values like `$_SESSION['userid']` on the server so they can't be changed by the client and you'll always know the userid and if the person with that session is logged in.